# How to display a views slideshow placeholder?

Tags: views, blocks, javascript

I have a site where the user can add images to the content types page and (custom) project. These images are displayed in a views slideshow based on contextual filter on each page/project in a block. The slideshows are header slideshows, so there must be a placeholder slideshow, if no images are added. How can i accomplish this ? I need a solution where no further maintenance by the user is needed.

Do i have to put some if/else in the page.tpl.php or is there some more elegant way ?

Answer (score 1):

Your slideshow is a View. So:

1. Go to edit page of your view
2. Expand "Advanced" field set
3. Add new item into "NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR"
4. Choose "Global: Text area"
5. Add your placeholder html there. E.g. `<div class="no-images-placeholder">NO-IMAGES</div>`
6. Save View

Answer (score 1):

The Answer of milkovsky pointed me in the right direction:

1. Go to edit page of your view
2. Expand "Advanced" field set
3. Add new item into "NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR"
4. "Choose "Global: View area"
5. View to insert -> choose the placeholder view to display instead
6. Add another contextual filter "GLobal Null"
7. WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE -> Display contents of "No Result found"
8. Save view